# Read File allocation table without using System.IO

Tags: c#

i have a problem which is that i want to extract information about FAT(file allocation table) in C# but the restriction is i cannot use System.IO
so How i get drive types?cluster information e.t.c

Comment: Is there a sensible reason why you can't use System.IO?

Comment: More importantly, is this stuff even available via System.IO? I don't remember seeing low level stuff such as filesystem details there.

Comment: @Matti - Fair comment, the answer may well be "system.IO doesn't provide low enough level of detail", but it's always worth verifying the assumptions on questions :)

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to use WMI. I'm not sure which classes you'd need to use but I'd start looking at the  `Win32_LogicalDisk`class as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173%28VS.85%29.aspx).