# Read/Write operation on Fat table with out using System.IO in C#

Tags: c#, windows, function

Hi i am new to the system programming...i want to read information from fat table like total sector,total physical drive,containing logical drive types and as well containing files in the drives(like their file size,when accessed)with all information of files..and then display of these files with respect of their hierarchy at GUI.

this is easy if we use System.IO namespace.but it is restricted for me.so please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read File allocation table without using System.IO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948684/read-file-allocation-table-without-using-system-io)

Comment: Don't just open new questions asking the same thing, update your previous question in that case.

Comment: could you explain why you can't use System.IO?  That may help clarify which alternatives are viable, like "just do what System.IO does"

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to DllImport the Kernel32.dll to do this.

```
internal extern static int ReadFile(SafeFileHandle handle, byte[] bytes,
int numBytesToRead, out int numBytesRead, IntPtr overlapped_MustBeZero);

ReadFile(handleValue, buf, size, out read, IntPtr.Zero);
```

As an example above of reading a file.

Head over to [pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.readfile#) for me details